# Images relates issue in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I used `Magento 1.9` suddenly I faced a problem in it .When i create a product and upload images, it is shown in back end and not show in front end.But after this when I edit the same product and add one more image in it then in front end it shown second images.

What is the reason of this strange behavior.May be this is all because before a week I enabled cache and due to some issue in it I again disable it.

Till now it tried solution:- 1.Clear cache and index many times.(My cache is disabled).

2.Rename `.htaccess` of `media` folder.

3.Give `777` permission to`media` folder.

Please see the image attached.

`/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/117ec6be2be2581904bec9efa7f5ed31/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg` (Placeholder shown)

`/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/580x580/0fb09527b0cea108ca47a7bcd7e27e43/6/_/6_1_2.jpg`(Image shown which is uploaded second time)

[image]

Comment: make sure that images are checked in backend and uncheck exclude

Comment: @Ritesh you are using any extension can you please share ur url

Comment: http://jeenam.com.au/

Comment: Please see "Today is friday".
There is 2 images one is placeholder that is uploaded at the time of product creation and second is upload at the time of product edit.
And both the images are clearly visible in admin.

Answer (score 0):

You set the Base Image check box next to the desired image? 
You can also eliminate this image by setting the checkbox Exclude.

The template file is responsible for the output image `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml`.

Maybe you have not used a standard template? then check this file in your template.

Comment: Ok
But previously uploaded images are clearly shown in front end.If the file is infected then old images are also not visible and one more thing as i said early that when I edit the product then images will be shown not in first time.

Comment: What does the output on the product page `echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );`

Comment: I used the above code to get image but this code of line also return placeholder image.Now what can I do..?